# Is there a way of letting hair particles "grow"?

Tags: particles

I have a hair particle system making a forest and I need those trees to grow, like in timelapse. I don't need them to grow from seedlings, it's more like appearing one after another in about 50 frames. I tried to animate the count, which is not possible and to animate the size, which is sort of possible, but for some reason only one keyframe can be added.

Comment: Try animating the scale of the trees themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the scale of particles cannot be animated, but there is a simple work around: animate the scale of the objects that are being distributed by the particle system.